# Get resources based on a value created using count

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am using Terraform v12.19 with the aws provider v2.34.0.
Imagine, I have a resource generated with a count value:

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "role" {
  count = length(var.somevariable)
  name = var.somevariable[count.index]
}
```

Later on, I want to reference one specific resource instance in that way, e. g.:

```
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "polatt" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.role["TheRoleNameIWant"].id
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/..."
}
```

I don't know the index, I can just rely on the name, provided by the variable. Thats because the values of the variable are provided by an external source and the order could change...

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Use `for_each` instead of `count`.

Comment: Ok, I simplified the question a little bit. I already have a dynamic block in the resource that uses a for_each. I dont think that it is possible to use nested for_each statements.

Comment: Why don't you think that's possible? Have you tried? Do you get an error message when you do so? It might be useful to add that to the question if so.

Comment: Regardless of for_each: How would I refer to the role if it had been created using for_each? So this line here: `role = aws_iam_role.role.mydynamicrolename.id` How should this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this using the `index` terraform function.

Here's a minimal example using `null_resources` to test it out

```
locals {
  role_names = [
    "role-a",
    "role-b",
    "role-c",
    "role-d",
  ]

  target_role_name = "role-c"
}

resource "null_resource" "hi" {
  count = length(local.role_names)
}

output "target_resource" {
  value = null_resource.hi[index(local.role_names, local.target_role_name)].id
}

output "all_resources" {
  value = [for r in null_resource.hi : r.id]
}
```

This outputs, for example

```
all_resources = [
  "4350570701002192774",
  "9173388682753384584",
  "1634695740603384613",
  "2098863759573339880",
]
target_resource = 1634695740603384613
```

So your example, I suppose, would look like

```
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "polatt" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.role[index(var.somevariable, "TheRoleNameIWant")].id
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/..."
}
```

## Update

Your comment below mentions that you actually have a more complicated data structure than just a list of names. I just wanted to mention that you can derive names from your JSON structure.

Assuming you have something like the following

```
variable "role_values" {
  value = [
    {
      name = "foo",
      other = "details",
      fields = 3
    },
    {
      name = "bar",
      other = "yet more details",
      fields = 3
    }
  ]
}
```

you could derive just the names by using a local and the newer `for` loops TF 0.12 offers

```
locals {
  role_names = [for role in var.role_values: role.name]
}
```

That way you don't have to store the names twice.

Comment: Yeah, solved it now in a similar way. var.somevariable are the names (strings). In my example, I dont have just strings (in fact its a json file behind), but if you store the names separatelly just for the index everything works as it should. Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: @Stefan ah yes, the more complicated data structures make it more complicated. I'm going to update my answer to mention how you could do that.